# How do I fix the layout and size of a floating html div?

Tags: html, css

Below is the html in question

By default it appears as:
 [image]

Which is completely wrong, it should be on two lines and it should also look "pretty" but it looks pretty ugly at the moment.

The aim of the box is so that it looks like a "Loading" box which after time (already incorporated into my main bit of code) for it to disappear once loaded, so the only problem with this at the moment is that it looks ugly and doesn't layout correctly :(

The reason I have two div blocks inside the main div is because they're going to be different size and color text (I think)

If anyone has a completely different looking loading message/bar/popup that they think I would like to use please feel free to post.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .loading1 a {
            position: fixed;
            cursor: pointer;
            left: 50%;
            top: 10%;
            color: white;
            padding-left: 5px;
            }

            .loading2 a {
            position: fixed;
            cursor: pointer;
            left: 50%;
            top: 10%;
            color: white;
            padding-left: 5px;
            }

            .loading {
            z-index: 999;
            position: fixed;
            left: 50%;
            top: 10%;
            width: 150px;
            height: 80px;
            border: 1px solid white;
            -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background: #D8B93F;
            }

            #circularG{
            position:relative;
            width:25px;
            height:25px}

            .circularG{
            position:absolute;
            background-color:#0E4216;
            width:6px;
            height:6px;
            -moz-border-radius:4px;
            -moz-animation-name:bounce_circularG;
            -moz-animation-duration:1.12s;
            -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
            -moz-animation-direction:linear;
            -webkit-border-radius:4px;
            -webkit-animation-name:bounce_circularG;
            -webkit-animation-duration:1.12s;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
            -webkit-animation-direction:linear;
            -o-border-radius:4px;
            -o-animation-name:bounce_circularG;
            -o-animation-duration:1.12s;
            -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
            -o-animation-direction:linear;
            -ms-border-radius:4px;
            -ms-animation-name:bounce_circularG;
            -ms-animation-duration:1.12s;
            -ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
            -ms-animation-direction:linear;
            }

            #circularG_1{
            left:0;
            top:10px;
            -moz-animation-delay:0.42s;
            -webkit-animation-delay:0.42s;
            -o-animation-delay:0.42s;
            -ms-animation-delay:0.42s;
            }

            #circularG_2{
            left:3px;
            top:3px;
            -moz-animation-delay:0.56s;
            -webkit-animation-delay:0.56s;
            -o-animation-delay:0.56s;
            -ms-animation-delay:0.56s;
            }

            #circularG_3{
            top:0;
            left:10px;
            -moz-animation-delay:0.7s;
            -webkit-animation-delay:0.7s;
            -o-animation-delay:0.7s;
            -ms-animation-delay:0.7s;
            }

            #circularG_4{
            right:3px;
            top:3px;
            -moz-animation-delay:0.84s;
            -webkit-animation-delay:0.84s;
            -o-animation-delay:0.84s;
            -ms-animation-delay:0.84s;
            }

            #circularG_5{
            right:0;
            top:10px;
            -moz-animation-delay:0.98s;
            -webkit-animation-delay:0.98s;
            -o-animation-delay:0.98s;
            -ms-animation-delay:0.98s;
            }

            #circularG_6{
            right:3px;
            bottom:3px;
            -moz-animation-delay:1.12s;
            -webkit-animation-delay:1.12s;
            -o-animation-delay:1.12s;
            -ms-animation-delay:1.12s;
            }

            #circularG_7{
            left:10px;
            bottom:0;
            -moz-animation-delay:1.26s;
            -webkit-animation-delay:1.26s;
            -o-animation-delay:1.26s;
            -ms-animation-delay:1.26s;
            }

            #circularG_8{
            left:3px;
            bottom:3px;
            -moz-animation-delay:1.4s;
            -webkit-animation-delay:1.4s;
            -o-animation-delay:1.4s;
            -ms-animation-delay:1.4s;
            }

            @-moz-keyframes bounce_circularG{
            0%{
            -moz-transform:scale(1)}

            100%{
            -moz-transform:scale(.3)}

            }

            @-webkit-keyframes bounce_circularG{
            0%{
            -webkit-transform:scale(1)}

            100%{
            -webkit-transform:scale(.3)}

            }

            @-o-keyframes bounce_circularG{
            0%{
            -o-transform:scale(1)}

            100%{
            -o-transform:scale(.3)}

            }

            @-ms-keyframes bounce_circularG{
            0%{
            -ms-transform:scale(1)}

            100%{
            -ms-transform:scale(.3)}

            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="loading"><div id="circularG">
            <div id="circularG_1" class="circularG">
            </div>
            <div id="circularG_2" class="circularG">
            </div>
            <div id="circularG_3" class="circularG">
            </div>
            <div id="circularG_4" class="circularG">
            </div>
            <div id="circularG_5" class="circularG">
            </div>
            <div id="circularG_6" class="circularG">
            </div>
            <div id="circularG_7" class="circularG">
            </div>
            <div id="circularG_8" class="circularG">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="loading1"><a>Loading, Please Wait...</a></div><div class="loading2"><br><a>(click to abort)</a></div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing anything here, but your classes are all listed as being fixed at 50% left and 10% top, which would explain why they're rendering overlapping one another

Comment: why you must make the position become fixed if you want to make that look clean & i think you put the left and top in the same value, it would make them pile up

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a2LkM/ for all you jsfiddlers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need the `position:fixed`, `top` and `left` on anything inside the loading box. I have also made some changes to the positioning and spacing. Hope you like it!

http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/9eZNQ/

HTML

```
<div class="loading">
    <div id="circularG">
        <div id="circularG_1" class="circularG"></div>
        <div id="circularG_2" class="circularG"></div>
        <div id="circularG_3" class="circularG"></div>
        <div id="circularG_4" class="circularG"></div>
        <div id="circularG_5" class="circularG"></div>
        <div id="circularG_6" class="circularG"></div>
        <div id="circularG_7" class="circularG"></div>
        <div id="circularG_8" class="circularG"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="loadingText">
        Loading, Please Wait... 
        <a href="#">(click to abort)</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.loadingText {
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.loadingText a {
    line-height: 32px;
    color: inherit;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.loading {
    z-index: 999;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 170px;
    height: 90px;
    margin-left: -95px;
    margin-top: -55px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    text-align: center;
}
#circularG {
    position:relative;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    margin: 5px auto 15px auto;
}
.circularG {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: white;
    width:6px;
    height:6px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-animation-name:bounce_circularG;
    -moz-animation-duration:1.12s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -moz-animation-direction:linear;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-animation-name:bounce_circularG;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1.12s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction:linear;
    -o-border-radius:4px;
    -o-animation-name:bounce_circularG;
    -o-animation-duration:1.12s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -o-animation-direction:linear;
    -ms-border-radius:4px;
    -ms-animation-name:bounce_circularG;
    -ms-animation-duration:1.12s;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -ms-animation-direction:linear;
}
#circularG_1 {
    left:0;
    top:10px;
    -moz-animation-delay:0.42s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.42s;
    -o-animation-delay:0.42s;
    -ms-animation-delay:0.42s;
}
#circularG_2 {
    left:3px;
    top:3px;
    -moz-animation-delay:0.56s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.56s;
    -o-animation-delay:0.56s;
    -ms-animation-delay:0.56s;
}
#circularG_3 {
    top:0;
    left:10px;
    -moz-animation-delay:0.7s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.7s;
    -o-animation-delay:0.7s;
    -ms-animation-delay:0.7s;
}
#circularG_4 {
    right:3px;
    top:3px;
    -moz-animation-delay:0.84s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.84s;
    -o-animation-delay:0.84s;
    -ms-animation-delay:0.84s;
}
#circularG_5 {
    right:0;
    top:10px;
    -moz-animation-delay:0.98s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.98s;
    -o-animation-delay:0.98s;
    -ms-animation-delay:0.98s;
}
#circularG_6 {
    right:3px;
    bottom:3px;
    -moz-animation-delay:1.12s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1.12s;
    -o-animation-delay:1.12s;
    -ms-animation-delay:1.12s;
}
#circularG_7 {
    left:10px;
    bottom:0;
    -moz-animation-delay:1.26s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1.26s;
    -o-animation-delay:1.26s;
    -ms-animation-delay:1.26s;
}
#circularG_8 {
    left:3px;
    bottom:3px;
    -moz-animation-delay:1.4s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1.4s;
    -o-animation-delay:1.4s;
    -ms-animation-delay:1.4s;
}
@-moz-keyframes bounce_circularG {
    0% {
        -moz-transform:scale(1)
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform:scale(.3)
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce_circularG {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform:scale(1)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:scale(.3)
    }
}
@-o-keyframes bounce_circularG {
    0% {
        -o-transform:scale(1)
    }
    100% {
        -o-transform:scale(.3)
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes bounce_circularG {
    0% {
        -ms-transform:scale(1)
    }
    100% {
        -ms-transform:scale(.3)
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, it looks very pretty, professional and tidy the color schemes were only slightly different to what I first thought of however I prefer your color scheme than mine (the orange in the example was just example colors), thank you for your help and I facepalmed after the first person pointed out my mistake on the positioning.

Answer (score 4):

```
.loading1 a {
            position: fixed;
            cursor: pointer;
            left: 50%;
            top: 10%;
            color: white;
            padding-left: 5px;
            }

            .loading2 a {
            position: fixed;
            cursor: pointer;
            left: 50%;
            top: 10%;
            color: white;
            padding-left: 5px;
            }

            .loading {
            z-index: 999;
            position: fixed;
            left: 50%;
            top: 10%;
            width: 150px;
            height: 80px;
            border: 1px solid white;
            -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background: #D8B93F;
            }
```

You need to take a look at your positioning. s you have all 3 of them set to fixed and left = 50% and top = 10%.

Due to this they will all sit in the same place on the page.

Have a look at [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) it explains it all in there and you can have a mess about with that :)

Answer (score 3):

You have them set to fixed to `left: 50%; top: 10%;`

Try changing

```
.loading1 a {
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 50%;
  top: 10%;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.loading2 a {
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 50%;
  top: 10%;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 5px;
 }
```

To:

```
.loading1 a {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 5%;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.loading2 a {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 5%;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XDVLE/1/). In this fiddle I removed your `<br>`. It is two different divs so there is a break already.